# Git for Windows changes commit message?

Tags: windows, bash, git

After doing

```
git commit -am '/logs whatever'
```

I end up with commit message `C:/Program Files/Git/logs whatever`. How does this happen? I did not succeed in finding any related information by googling things like 'git commit message autocomplete'.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

**Additional investigation** The path does not have to exist, it's just appended to `C:/Program Files/Git`, but if it exists, things can be different (notice `/usr/`, both paths exist):

```
$ git commit -am '/bin/git.exe something'
[master 22f9915] C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/git.exe something
```

Comment: Strange, I did not reproduced the issue, using single or double quotes, with a CMD or a bash session...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/577#issuecomment-166118846). Johannes Schindelin, maintainer of Git for Windows, describes it and possible fixes:

> If you specify command-line options starting with a slash, POSIX-to-Windows path conversion will kick in converting e.g. "`/usr/bin/bash.exe`" to "`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`". When that is not desired -- e.g. "`--upload-pack=/opt/git/bin/git-upload-pack`" or "`-L/regex/`" -- you need to set the environment variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV` temporarily, like so:
>
> `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 git blame -L/pathconv/ msys2_path_conv.cc`
>
> Alternatively, you can double the first slash to avoid POSIX-to-Windows path conversion.

Even though in your case this is not a path as such, just the fact that the message starts with a slash must be triggering this behavior.